# Only admin can see products page for Drupal Commerce

Tags: users, commerce, notifications

I created a subscription product with Drupal Commerce and commerce_sp modules.  I then created a view to display the product subscription I want and as Administrator I can see the product on the product page just fine, but as an authenticated user the page is available to view via a link in a menu, but the page doesn't show the list of products, just white space.  I've gone into the permissions to make sure the user can purchase an item and go through the check out forms, and the view has no access control on it.

I'm pulling my hair out over this, I have no idea why no one but the admin can see the products listed on the page.

Comment: The only way I have been able to solve this is by enabling the permission: Allow (user role) to view ANY subscription products.

Comment: You can also see this longstanding issue in the queue: http://drupal.org/node/1276450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Admin menu > People > Permission: 
Check 'Authenticated User' for:

1. 'View any product of any type' from 'Product' group
2. 'Access checkout' from 'Checkout' group